# Is there a way to make tika-server.jar permanent if I clean "temp" later?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-tika, pdftotext, tika-server

I'm using **TIKA parser** for extracting text from PDF but it downloads a **tika-server.jar** into C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp. Is there a way to make this permanent if I clean "temp" later?
Can we use TIKA parser in production?

Tried other libraries like **pyPdf2** but it works for some file and doesn't for other files.

Comment: Download the Tika Server jar manually, place it somewhere stable, then set the path to the jar when you run the python wrapper?

Comment: yeah, we can pass the URL in the parser as a parameter, In prod trying to deploy in a separate container and call parser with URL.